# How to implement shared mutable state in a rust-axum backend server?

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I am working on what can best be described as a ChatGpt clone website using Axum and HTMX. I'm really struggling to understand how shared mutable state can be implemented on an Axum backend. I've been referencing [this example](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/key-value-store/src/main.rs) but when I finally broke down and cloned the example, it didn't even compile.. So I'm worried I'm referencing outdated information.
My current main() function is this:

```
pub type SharedState = Arc<RwLock<AppState>>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct AppState {
    chats: Vec<Chat>,
    current_chat_idx: u8,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let state = SharedState::default();
    let router: Router<()> = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(home))
        .route("/chat/:current_agent", get(chat))
        .route("/snippets/chat_list", get(chat_list))
        .route("/snippets/chat_buttons", get(chat_buttons))
        .route("/snippets/chat_history", get(chat_history))
        .layer(Extension(state))
        .with_state(AppState::default());
    axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(router.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}
```

The above code compiles and runs but I'm confused. If .layer() gives me access the the SharedState struct, why do I then need to pass another instance of AppState with the .with_state() method? Isn't this a waste of memory and completely pointless disregarding that this is the only way to get this to compile?

I've written these endpoints using `state: Extension<SharedState>` as a parameter:

```
pub async fn chat_history(state: Extension<SharedState>) -> Html<String> {
    let mut shared_state = state.write().unwrap();
    let agent = shared_state.current_agent();

    let messages: Vec<MessageRender> = agent
        .memory
        .cache()
        .as_ref()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|m| MessageRender::from(m))
        .collect();

    let template = fs::read_to_string("src/html/snippets/chat_history.html").unwrap();
    let r = render!(&template, messages => messages);
    Html(r)
}
pub async fn chat_list(state: Extension<SharedState>) -> Html<String> {
    let shared_state = state.read().unwrap();
    let current_chat_name = &shared_state.current_chat().name;
    println!(
        "Chat list current name, idx: {}, {}",
        current_chat_name,
        state.read().unwrap().current_chat_idx
    );

    let template = fs::read_to_string("src/html/snippets/chat_list.html").unwrap();
    let r = render!(&template,chats => shared_state.chats, current_chat_name => current_chat_name );
    Html(r)
}
```

they both compile fine and behave as expected on the webpage. But when I try to compile this endpoint:

```
pub async fn post_prompt(
    state: Extension<super::SharedState>,
    Form(prompt): Form<PromptForm>,
) -> Html<String> {
    let mut shared_state = state.write().unwrap();
    let agent = shared_state.current_agent();

    let res = agent.prompt(prompt.user_input).await;
    if let Ok(response) = res {
        println!("{}", response);
    }
    Html(String::new())
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(axum::Extension<Arc<std::sync::RwLock<AppState>>>, Form<PromptForm>) -> impl Future<Output = axum::response::Html<std::string::String>> {api::post_prompt}: Handler<_, _, _>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:83:58
    |
83  |         .route("/chat/:current_agent/prompt_agent", post(post_prompt))
    |                                                     ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Handler<_, _, _>` is not implemented for fn item `fn(axum::Extension<Arc<std::sync::RwLock<AppState>>>, Form<PromptForm>) -> impl Future<Output = axum::response::Html<std::string::String>> {api::post_prompt}`
    |                                                     |
    |                                                     required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Handler<T, S, B>`:
              <Layered<L, H, T, S, B, B2> as Handler<T, S, B2>>
              <MethodRouter<S, B> as Handler<(), S, B>>
```

I tried removing the Form parameter to try compile using only the Extension parameter, but I struggled with the same error. Really would appreciate some help

Comment: Can't really compile the code myself to see what the problem could be because there are too many types and methods in your code for which you haven't given us the definition.

Comment: You can add [`#[debug_handler]`](https://docs.rs/axum-macros/latest/axum_macros/attr.debug_handler.html) on `post_prompt` to get better error messages. Without that and a [reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) its not clear what the problem may be.

Comment: I added `#[debug_handler]` and it looks like the problem is that I'm awaiting on the `agent` which results from a RWLockGuard which doesn't implement `Send` so I can't await it

Comment: @voidkandy You should use [tokio's `RwLock`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.RwLock.html) if you need to hold a guard across an await point. Its guards are `Send`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `post_prompt` endpoint wasn't compiling was because It was awaiting a `std::sync::RWLock`, changing the RWLock to a `tokio::sync::RWLock` fixed the issue and the handler code now compiles